# Adjusting the height of a div to match that of another column

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, image, layout

This code checks whether an image whose parent is `.papers.left` has completely loaded into `DOM` and if yes then the background of its `right` content's height has to be same as the background of this images `parent`. So below is html to understand the structure

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="papers left text-center">
               <img src="http://wowthemes.net/demo/leroy/img/dummies/18.jpg" alt=""><br /> 
<!--Once the above image is completely loaded I want to set `.papers.right` height as same as `.papers.left` div-->
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="papers right text-center">
               <blockquote>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages." <cite>Jogn De, Birthday Event<br /><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i></cite> 
               </blockquote>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So to set same height I have written below js code which will set the height of `div.papers.right` same as `div.papers.left` but only when the image is loaded completely

```
$('img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.papers.left').length)
    {
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right').height($(this).closest('.papers.left').height());
        })
    }
})
```

Can the above piece of jQuery code be optimized? I am not sure whether the above code can be optimized to some simple one.

---

**Update**
I just realized one more requirement so that whichever's height is greater assign that `height` to other one and I've made below changes to code and I would like to know if there is any improvement that can be done to the below code. Extremely sorry for the inconvenience.

```
$('img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.papers.left').length)
    {
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            if ($(this).closest('.papers.left').height() > $(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right').height()) 
             //if left side has greater height assign it to right side
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right').height($(this).closest('.papers.left').height());
            else
            //vice versa                    
            $(this).closest('.papers.left').height($(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right').height());
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by optimized?

Comment: @sunny any shortening of the js code is possible? I feel its bit lengthy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save `$(this).closest('.papers.left')` into a local variable since you access it twice. This might improve performance. It can also enhance code readability:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.papers.left');
    if (parent.length)
    {
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right').height(parent.height());
        })
    }
})
```

---

As an add on to your code modification, I don't know that this is faster, but why not try assigning max height to both without checking which is taller? Something like:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.papers.left');
    if (parent.length)
    {
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            var sibling = $(this).closest('.row').find('.papers.right');
            var height = Math.max(parent.height(), sibling.height());
            parent.height(height);
            sibling.height(height);
        })
    }
```

})

It's certainly shorter and more readable. Why not test it out to see how the efficiency compares?

Comment: I know I shouldn't do this but I've updated by code to add one more requirement. Can you review it and let me know any changes can be done to improve performance?

Comment: That `var parent=` gives a syntax error..

Comment: I could have assigned max height but image height may vary and vice versa with text height too..

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. When does var parent give a syntax error? In the if statement or even outside the if statement (I told you I wasn't sure about the if statement)

Comment: in the `if` statement buddy.. yea I just tested and just informed about that..

Comment: ok I'll get rid of that in my answer. what about your other comment?

Comment: Are you suggesting to set max-height instead of height in jQuery?

Comment: **1.** Use `$('.papers.left img').each(` to minimize the iterations **2.** Cache `$(this)` instance